# TDD Browserify and ReactJS

Tags: mocha.js, reactjs, browserify

I'm trying to find a good, clean, way to test React components. I'm liking the idea of [mochify](https://www.npmjs.org/package/mochify) as it looks like it abstracts a lot of the hassle of test runners, works with webdriver/saucelabs, etc.

The trouble is that I'm using Browserify with various transforms for jsx, coffee, less, etc from the command line. And can't find how get mochify to run those transforms.

How do I do this?

Or is there a better option out there... [Karma](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/index.html) maybe?

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered using gulp to organize tasks? You could set up a browserify build and then run mocha tests automatically using something like gulp-mocha-phantomjs.

Comment: Yeah. I've used grunt and gulp pretty heavily on other projects. Was trying to keep it simple on this one. But that might be the easiest way.

Comment: I did tried JSPM and it works well.. Explained detailly in my blog post how to set-up and use TDD with react

http://www.undefinednull.com/2015/05/03/react-tdd-example-unit-testing-and-building-a-react-component-with-jest-gulp-and-react-test-utils/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browserify transforms can also be specified in `package.json`, for example:

```
...
"devDependencies": {
  "browserify": "*",
  "coffeeify": "^0.6.0",
  "mocha": "*",
  "mochify": "*",
  "reactify": "^0.13.1"
},
"browserify": {
  "transform": [
    "coffeeify",
    "reactify"
  ]
},
...
```

In your test files, just requires the actual component file using relative path, and write tests as you normally do with mocha:

```
var React = require('react/addons');
var TestUtils = React.addons.TestUtils;
var MyComponent = require('../src/app/MyComponent');
...
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** Mochify now supports additional transforms and plugins with `--transform` and `--plugin`.

This problem will be addressed in a future release of Mochify.

Make sure to watch [the issue on GitHub](https://github.com/mantoni/mochify.js/issues/17).